# How to setup php-fpm and nginx on 2 separate containers with different volume paths

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I'm attempting to setup a development environment using docker using 2 containers: `nginx` and `php7-fpm`.

What I want to happen is when a user visits any URL that contains `/api` it uses php-fpm, but everything else is loaded from `/var/www/html`.

Here is my configuration:

**site.conf:**

```
server {
    index index.html;
    server_name impressive.local;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;

    location /api {
        index index.php;
        alias /var/www/api;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass php:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
    - ./frontend/public:/var/www/html
    - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
  links: [ php ]
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  environment:
    - NGINX_HOST=http://impressive.local
    - NGINX_PORT=80

php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
    - ./api:/var/www/api
```

This doesn't work as expected and when I visit `impressive.local/api` I get the following error in logs:

```
web_1  | 2019/01/10 12:23:47 [error] 6#6: *1 "/var/www/api/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: impressive.local, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", host: "impressive.local:8080"
```

I realize that the php-fpm container is the one that contains the `/var/www/api` directory and not nginx. With my configuration nginx is trying to `alias` to a non existent path and is thus failing.

My question is how is possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I use exactly this configuration for all of my Laravel apps.

Here is an example of my configuration...

```
version: '2'
services:

  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=x.x.x.x"
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 8080:80
```

As you can see you specify to use the volume from your web container.

Answer (score -1):

I think the configuration file is invalid; try this code to fix [ docker-compose.yml and site.conf ]

> **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/public:/var/www/html
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=impressive.local
      - NGINX_PORT=80
    links:
      - php

  php:
      image: php:7-fpm
      volumes:
      - ./api:/var/www/api
      - ./frontend/public:/var/www/html
```

> **site.conf**

```
server {
  index index.html index.php;
  server_name impressive.local;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  root /var/www/html;

  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location /api/ {
    alias /var/www/api;
  }

  location ~  ^/api/(.+\.php)$ {
    alias /var/www/api;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on php:9000
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }

  # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
  # concurs with nginx's one
  #
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

finally, run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`

Comment: Why are you adding the root location /frontend/public:/var/www/html on both container nginx and php container